# Spring Boot application.properties not found after exporting to jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I run Spring Boot in Eclipse it works great. The  `application.properties` file is visible in resources folder. However when I export it to a RUNNABLE JAR, and try to run it from `cmd` it says `application.properties` not found.

Here is configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

pom build

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TEST</name>
    <description>TEST</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>

          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-configuration-processor
            </artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-boot-configuration-processor
            </artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build> 
    
         <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <localCheckout>false</localCheckout>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>false</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins> 
        
    
        
        
    </build>

</project>
```

It is located in src/main/resources

Why is it not exported to JAR?

Comment: Can we see the rest of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Where do you have that @Configuration? How are you generating the jar?

Comment: posted full pom

Comment: i;m generating JAR by clicking "Export to Runnable JAR" in Eclipse

Comment: @Configuration is annotation for one of my classes that is pulling properties from application.properties

Comment: Spring Boot uses custom packaging logic; just use `mvn package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export to Runnable JAR` in eclipse won't work with spring-boot project. You have to use this plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.mainclass</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and running `mvn package` will create a jar with dependencies and everything in resources folder in `target` directory.